# Updating a variable in Angular $interval causes other functions to run

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried to simplify this problem as much as possible so ignore how pointless this example is :)

I have a directive that is displaying a timer. Every 500ms it increments the counter.

JS

```
.directive('testTimer', function($interval) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            var count;
            scope.counter = 0;
            count = $interval(tick, 500);

            function tick() {
                scope.counter++;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<test-timer>{{counter}}</test-timer>
```

Every time tick() runs, functions in my controller also run

```
.controller('testController', function($scope) {
    $scope.array = [
        1,2,3
    ]

    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        console.log('Why does this run every time tick runs?')
        return num;
    }

})
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="testController">
<div ng-repeat="number in array">
    {{getNumber(number)}}
</div>


<test-timer>{{counter}}</test-timer>
```

I've tried using [invokeApply = false](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) in my $interval but then the counter doesn't update in the DOM. How do I prevent my directive from running other functions in my controller over and over but still have it update the counter in the view?

Here is a JS fiddle showing the issue (look at the console logs)
https://jsfiddle.net/marmite/nf4c18tx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got a work around for this specific case

I pass the element to the link function of the directive.

```
link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
```

then, instead of binding the value of the counter, I can update it manually

```
angular.element(el[0]).html(counter++);
```

And finally, I tell my $interval to not invokeApply by passing false as the 4th parameter.

```
count = $interval(tick, 500, 0, false);
```

Link to fixed JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/marmite/9ac5j76c/

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour.

Angular runs so called [digest loop](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) to detect and propagate changes. The only way to update value returned by `{{ getNumber(number) }}` is by evaluating the function call `getNumber(number)` because Angular doesn't know if you've changed its return value or not. The digest loop is invoked by [`$interval()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) which is a wrapper around standard JavaScript `setInterval()`.

You can modify your code to use just `setInterval()` and you can see that `getNumber()` isn't called any more, because there's nothing to trigger the digest loop.

Your updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7Ljus149/1/

To answer your question: Don't return the numeric value from function. I don't know what's your use-case but I think you don't need to use a function call in `{{ }}`. It can also lead to significant performance issues and in general it's almost always better to avoid it.

Comment: In my actual use case the timer is on every page. There are many pages and they all do all sorts of different things. Returning a number from a function in ng-repeat was just a simple way to demonstrate the problem. I was hoping that I could do something to tell the directive to not care about anything except itself so it doesn't trigger everything else's digest.